# What python concept causes this result?

Tags: python

So I was studying for an exam and i made a simple function to review 'sequential processing' and then I made this function(s) that turn a string input of whitespaced numbers into a list and scan to find the highest, but my conditional seems to think 8 is greater than 20 and 23. Can someone tell my why this is?

```
def findMax(numberlist):
maxval = numberlist[0]
for i in numberlist[1:]:
    print("The value now is:\t",i,"\nThe max value is currently\t",maxval,"\n")
    if(i > maxval):
        maxval = i
print(maxval)
return maxval

def makeList(stringput):
    print(stringput)
    stringput = stringput.split(" ")
    for i in stringput[0:]:
        print("Value is:\t",i)
    return stringput

findMax(makeList(input("\nWhat test are to be sorted\n")))
```

This returned the result 8 from the input "1 20 8 21"

Edit:Sorry, new user
.

Comment: Convert each elements into integer and then perform the sorting.

Comment: Please provide your source code in plain text.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, it's useless in this way...

Comment: Why don't you copy the text? Please read  [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're entering strings into python. That means that all sorting is happening alphabetically - not numerically.

For example, if you sorted the following two word alphabetically, which would you put first?

> Apple
>
> Bee

Apple right? Because A comes before B. Lets try again

> 8
>
> 23

It's going to be 23 - 8 is later in the 'alphabet'.

If you want to sort these properly, cast them all to ints first. Or use a library such as [natsorted](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort).

Comment: So simple now you explain it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So, you basically need to cast each string representation of integers to an integer by using `int()`.  So, `'20' < '8'` because 2 comes before 8 in ASCII order.  When checking for which string is greater, each character is compared to see which is larger, it doesn't acknowledge the context of the `'0'` behind the `'2'`. But `int('20') < int('8')` because of how the number line works (over simplified).

You can do this all via a list comprehension:

```
stringput = [int(val) for val in stringput]
```

Result:

```
def findMax(numberlist):
    maxval = numberlist[0]
    for i in numberlist[1:]:
        print("The value now is:\t",i,"\nThe max value is currently\t",maxval,"\n")
        if(i > maxval):
            maxval = i
    print(maxval)
    return maxval

def makeList(stringput):
    print(stringput)
    stringput = stringput.split(" ")
    stringput = [int(val) for val in stringput] #new line
    for i in stringput[0:]:
        print("Value is:\t",i)
    return stringput

findMax(makeList(input("\nWhat test are to be sorted\n")))
```

Comment: Thanks. The char to int conversion totally slipped my mind.

Comment: Just a heads up, it's technically string to int.  Char is a type in C++ which represents a single character or signed 8-bit int.  So, technically it's string to int (because there is more than one character).  I'm not trying to go out of my way to correct you, I just thought that was important to point out.  Thanks for the compliment.